# Logic statements in R: Are values in column X found in column Y?

Tags: r, logic

I am still a beginner programmer so please forgive my ignorance if this questions is extremely simplistic.

Let's suppose I have a dataframe defined by the following:

```
> data=as.data.frame(c('white','brown','black','blue','red','yellow'))
> colnames(data)='Colors'
> data
  Colors
1  white
2  brown
3  black
4   blue
5    red
6 yellow
```

Assume now that I need to know if the values of this dataframe are contained within another dataframe 'valid' of different length, where 'valid' is defined by the following:

```
> valid=as.data.frame(c('red','blue','white'))
> colnames(valid)='valid colors'
> valid
valid colors
1          red
2         blue
3        white
```

Now I would like to create a new column in 'data' that flags whether or not the color in the first column of data is contained within the 'valid' dataset to get the following:

```
> data
  Colors valid
1  white   Yes
2  brown    No
3  black    No
4   blue   Yes
5    red   Yes
6 yellow    No
```

The dataset I am working with is extremely large so doing this manually or over a loop is not a good option. I am sure there is an easy way of doing this but after hours of search, I am turning to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `%in%`:

```
data$valid <- data$Colors %in% valid$"valid colors"

> data
  Colors valid
1  white  TRUE
2  brown FALSE
3  black FALSE
4   blue  TRUE
5    red  TRUE
6 yellow FALSE
```